# AWS SDK for Laravel giving PHP fatal error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-s3, laravel

I installed the https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel‎ SDK and followed the instructions in the readme.md.  Everything installed, I put in my key, secret, region, etc. in the `/app/config/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel`.

**The Error I'm Getting**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found in /Volumes/Data/Users/chris/Sites/ln.com/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/src/Aws/Laravel/AwsServiceProvider.php on line 48
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Aws\\Common\\Aws' not found","file":"\/Volumes\/Data\/Users\/chris\/Sites\/ln.com\/vendor\/aws\/aws-sdk-php-laravel\/src\/Aws\/Laravel\/AwsServiceProvider.php","line":48}}
```

Line 48 of that file referenced above simply says:

```
$aws = Aws::factory($config);
```

**I installed per the instructions**

I put in my providers and aliases in /app/config/app.php with:

```
'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider'
```

in the providers array.

I put in:

```
'AWS' => 'Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade'
```

in the aliases section.

Then, I'm trying to use their same usage example:

```
    $s3 = AWS::get('s3');
$s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'    => 'My Bucket',
    'Key'       => 'My Key',
    'SourceFile'=> Config::get('settings.ProcessListings.image_dir') . $listing->mls_listing_id . "/test.txt"
                ));
```

**What I've Tried**

My only thoughts here were that in my file that I'm trying to use the SDK in, at the top I have:

```
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
```

I've added to that:

```
use Aws\Laravel\AwsFacade;
use Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider;
```

and combinations of the two but neither work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you executed `composer dump-autoload -o` in your server?

Comment: Yes, same error even after the composer dump-autoload -o

Comment: Also did `composer update`? Because `Aws\Common\Aws` is part of `aws/aws-sdk-php` and it looks like it is not installed.

Comment: Interesting but running `code`composer update`code` returned an all new error:

Comment: Which error you're getting now?

Comment: Sorry, the error now is: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 170

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 170

Comment: Composer is not being able to resolve all dependencies due to lack of sufficient memory. You can try to delete or, better, rename the vendor folder, just to see if it works. Sometimes packages already installed also keep Composer busy doing calculations. If it doesn't work for you, you might need to copy `vendor/aws` manually to your server, or just add your full vendor to your git repository...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is in a class `Aws\Common\Aws` from `aws/aws-sdk-php` which is not available to composer (the autoloader). Those are steps that usually fix Laravel, when things like this happen and the problem is not on your source code, of course:

```
cd /your/application/dir

rm bootstrap/compiled.php

rm -rf vendor (or just rename your vendor folder to test)

composer update --no-dev
```

Comment: This will remove the ´/vendor/autoload.php´ which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but, I've come across this problem recently and I didn't want to remove my compiled packages. In my case, running `php artisan config:cache` was throwing that error. So what I did, I found `Aws\\Laravel\\AwsServiceProvider` in `bootstrap/cache/services.php` and removed them which solved the issue.