# Amazon SES with Laravel 5

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have integrated `aws-sdk-php-laravel` in my Laravel project. After integration I got the following error:

> FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS SDK for Laravel giving PHP fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785217/aws-sdk-for-laravel-giving-php-fatal-error)

Comment: Did you actually add `Aws\Laravel\AwsServiceProvider` to the `providers` array in your *config/app.php* file?